# Regroup QuerySet por ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Estoy trabajando con django y tengo que recuperar lo registros de un modelo de llamado Restaurante, este tiene atributos como Nombre, Dirección, Telefono, Ciudad, etc. y además, tiene un atributo tipo_comida que es un `ManyToManyFiel`, con mi modelo llamado TipoComida, debido a que en un restaurante se pueden servir muchos tipos de comida (como mexicana, italiana, vegana, etc.) y un tipo de comida, puede ser ofrecido en muchos restaurantes y quiero recuperar todos los restaurantes de X ciudad y agruparlos por los tipos de comida, de la siguiente forma:

1. Comida Vegana

   - La compostera
   - Comidas Naturales
   - GreenRestaurant
   - Resto Bar
2. Comida Italiana

   - Resto Bar
   - Piere Pizzas
   - La compostera
3. Comida Mexicana

   - Jalisquitos
   - Tacos Maya
   - GreenRestaurant

He intentado hacerlo con la etiqueta {% regroup %}, pero me muestra la salida espera, adjunto el código de los modelos:

```
class TipoComida(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(
        max_length=150,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        help_text='Ingrese el nombre del tipo de comida',
        verbose_name='Nombre'
    )
    descripcion = models.CharField(
        max_length=250,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        help_text='Ingrese una breve descripción de este tipo de comida',
        verbose_name='Descripción'
    )


class Restaurante(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        help_text='Ingrese el nombre del restaurante',
        verbose_name='Nombre del Restaurante',
    )
    direccion = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        blank=False,
        null=True,
        help_text='Ingrese la dirección física del restaurante',
        verbose_name='Dirección'
    )
    telefono = PhoneNumberField(
        null=False,
        help_text='Ingrese el número telefónico del restaurante en el formato +999999999',
        unique=True,
        verbose_name='Número de Telefono'
    )
    ciudad = models.ForeignKey(
        Ciudad,
        related_name='ubicado_en',
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        blank=False,
        null=True,
        help_text='Seleccione la ciudad a la que pertenece este restaurante',
        verbose_name='Ciudad',
    )
    administrador = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='es_registrado_por',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        help_text='Usuario que añadió este restaurante',
        verbose_name='¿Quién lo registró?'
    )
    tipo_comida = models.ManyToManyField(
        TipoComida,
        help_text='Seleccione el/los tipos de comida servidos en este restaurante',
        related_name='restaurantes',
        verbose_name='Tipo de comida',
        blank=False
    )
```

Adjunto el código con la etiqueta {% regroup %}

```
{% regroup restaurantes by tipo_comida as tipo_comida_list %}
{% for tipo_comida in tipo_comida_list %}
  {{ tipo_comida.grouper }}
  {% for restaurante in tipo_comida.list %}
    <h1>{{ restaurante|upper }}</h1>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme y de antemano, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Al final, lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

```
comidas = TipoComida.objects.all()
group = {}
for comida in comidas:
    restaurante_key = '_'.join([str(restaurante.pk) for restaurante in comida.restaurante_set.all()])
        if not restaurante_key in group and restaurante_key != '':
            group[restaurante_key]={'restaurantes': comida.restaurante_set.all(), 'comidas':[]}
        if restaurante_key != '':
            group[restaurante_key]['comidas'].append(comida)    
context['group'] = group
```